# What's the best way to update a List on the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

If I have the following list in C# that was loaded from the database

```
List<User> user = GetUsers(foo);
```

and it was updated and I want to store those changes in the database what's the best way of doing it using SQL? It should insert the records added to that list, updated the modified records and delete the ones that are not present in the collection.

I'm no using the EntityFramework so I need to do this using SQL.

Comment: Well not everyone can choose the technologies they use at their job

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Copy this list to datatable and set datatable RowStat as (modified,deleted,new)
and update datatable using sqldataadapter

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that adds or inserts a row.  It searches for a row with a specific `UserID`.  If the row exists, it uses `update` to grant the user a point.  If the row does not exist, a new row is created with `insert`.

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=myServerAddress;" +
    "Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    var com = con.CreateCommand();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
    com.CommandText = @"
if exists (select * from YourTable where UserId = @UserId)
    update YourTable set TrollPoints = TrollPoints + 1 where UserId = @UserId
else
    insert YourTable (UserId, TrollPoints) values (@UserId, 1)
        ";
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The use of parameters allows the server to chache the execution plan, and also helps against SQL injection.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but my problem was with the items that were deleted in the client and are being sent to the server